# Chrome: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome

I am using jQuery in a web page.  When using `$` in Internet Explorer it works fine.  When referencing  `$` in Chrome or Firefox it fails with error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.
```

Screenshot:

[image]

With my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function divClick(sender, event)
      {
//       var chk = $(sender).find("input").first()[0];
         var chk = jQuery(sender).find("input").first()[0];
         alert("Works in ie");
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body>

<div onclick="divClick(this, event)">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** The browsers are being directed to a file on the local filesystem:

[image]

**Update**: Tried changing it to `jQuery`.

**Update**: Chrome finds the jquery file (i.e. no 404):

[image]

Comment: Check if `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` is in same folder as the html. `$ is not defined` is an error you get when jQuery lib is not included.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to wrap my function in a dom ready? And also how to move the click listener to the js? Look at my example below.

Comment: I had this same error.  In my case the problem was that my page was being accessed by way of https and my jquery script source was being accessed with http.  Adding an 's' to the script source solved my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And this question is here just to document the bug in Chrome and Firefox:

```
Html File encoding           IE9      Chrome
=========================    =======  ======
Windows-1252                 Works    Works
UTF-8 (without BOM)          Works    Works 
UTF-8 (with BOM EFBB)        Works    Works 
UTF-16 (with LE BOM FFFE)    Works    Fails
UTF-16 (with BE BOM FEFF)    Works    Fails
```

Presumably Chrome (and Firefox) assume that a separate `script` file has the same encoding as the `html` file.

Chrome then tries to read `jquery-1.7.2.js` as UTF-16, and is shocked to discover that the file is pure (Windows-1252) garbage.

Answer (score 5):

Check whether the path of `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` is correct. You can check in firebug if using firefox or chrome developer tool to see if the file is getting downloaded. You are mostly likely getting 404 for jQuery file due which $ is undefined on the page which is an alias to jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this error with Javascript in Firefox and Chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.
```

If you included jquery like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

And your server is configured to not allow javascript content to be downloaded and run at runtime, then you get the above error.  Take a look at the whole error:

```
[blocked] The page at https://yoursite.com/blah# ran insecure content 
from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js.
/blah#:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

What it means is your web server doesn't allow javascript content to be loaded on the fly.  It's a security risk because someone could inject evil stuff in there for you to download, and own your servers.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above was applicable for me on Chrome 49. 
I had to specify the type as "application/javascript" like so:

```
<script src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Using "text/javascript" was not working.

Comment: it really worked like a charm :) tried many solutions but could not find a fix like this

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var chk = jQuery(sender).find("input").first()[0];
```

Comment: Updated the question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to be wrapped in a dom ready:

```
$(function(){

  function divClick(sender, event)
  {
     var chk = $(sender).find("input").first()[0];
     alert("Works in ie");
  }

});
```

That will allow the function to fire only after the page has loaded. 
also your scripts should be loaded just before the closing HTML tag. not all the top. that will allow the page to load the HTML and css faster because it does not have to wait for the JS to load.

Also make sure you have the correct path to jQuery from your HTML.

Last thing,

Instead if having your click listener in inline HTML try moving it to the JS. It is just a cleaner more organized way to handle it.

```
$('.clickMe').click(function(){
    //do stuff here
})
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how to *wrap my function in a dom ready*? And also how to move the click listener to the `js`?

Comment: They are there the dom ready is the $(function(){    }) It is the jQuery short hand version.

for the click event reference this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/QgeD9/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the onclick in the html, I assigned everything via id in the Jquery code.

I'm not sure if you want to know if the div is checked or if the checkbox is checked. I put the input check in the code and commented out code if the div is clicked on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
// $('#divid').unbind("click").click(function(){
$('#someid').unbind("click").click(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
alert("checked");
}else{
alert("not checked");
}
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="divid"><input type="checkbox" id="someid"></div>

</body>
</html>
```